# Why does React Native says that "group1-shard.bin" file does not exist when it does? (tensorflowjs)

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, machine-learning

Currently, I'm trying to load my model with this function:

```
const loadModel = async () => {
  const modelJSON = require('../assets/models/model.json');
  const modelWeights = require('../assets/models/group1-shard.bin');
  const model = await tf
    .loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights))
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log('Error', e);
    });

  return model;
};
```

But when I try to require('../assets/models/group1-shard.bin) react-native says that it is "Unable to resolve module ../assets/models/group1-shard.bin", it also says that the file doesn't exist...

My file structure with the group1-shard.bin file: [image: Project file structure]

This is the full error message: [image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

I think if your code is in `App.js` you could have used the path `./assets/...` instead, and also consider adding the `bin` files in your metro `resolver.assetExts` array.